# What is the best way to apply layout styling to styled-components and React components used in different places on a site?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, styling, styled-components

I have React components and styled components that are used throughout my site. For example, buttons and cards. I have heard that using inline styling is a code smell and should be avoided.

However, to get stuff to look beautiful, css (particularly margins, padding and dimensions) still need to be applied to the components on a case by case basis.

I can see a number of options for this:

- Create compound components , each for use in different places e.g.
  `Card, Card.Padded, Card.Large`
- Create (potentially several) new components with different based on
  the ‘base’ component using styled components e.g. `styled(Card)`
  to create CardCharacters CardHomePage etc
- Use props to change the styling where different styles are needed
  e.g. `<Card withSomeMargins />` or `<Card margin={big} />`
- Use different ThemeProviders on each page to apply styling to the
  components

Can anyone give any advice on which approach(es) are ‘best-practice’ or preferred? I’m aware that different approaches might be better for different situations and there might not be a ‘best’ approach but I’m interested to hear people’s thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" approach would be using props to change the styles. Not really because it's a better practice with CSS-in-JS in general, but because that's the approach that Styled Components was designed for. Of course if you see that you are changing too much based on props, you should split it into a new styled component. So the answer is a mix of your second and third points.

Avoid stuff like passing specific style values through props (like width="100%") and instead pass flags or object keys to get the value you want from the theme.

Also, you may find that too much prop interpolation can lead to less readable styles. This approach can make it a bit better:

```
export const Card = styled.div(({ theme, margin }) => css`
  margin: ${margin ? theme.margin[margin] : 0};
  font-family: ${theme.font};
  font-size: ${theme.sizeBig};
  color: ${theme.dark};
  font-weight: ${theme.fontWeight}
`)
```